# Is the intersection of a closed interval with the rational compact in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I am self studying analysis.

This is what I have come across, A set is compact if its is closed and bounded, if the underlying topology is Hausdorff.

If I say for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} $ A set of the form $ [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} $ is compact as a subset of $\mathbb{Q} $ but not as a subset of $\mathbb{R} $? Since it is closed and bounded as a subset of the rationals, but not closed as a subset of the Reals.
Where $\mathbb{Q} $ and $\mathbb{R}$ are endowed with the usual metric.

But a discrete set is compact if and only if it is finite.

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: "Bounded" doesn't make sense in general topologies, only metric spaces. The topology of any metric space is Hausdorff. So you are already confusing things.

Comment: But here I used the metric topology, so shouldn't the notion of boundedness be applicable?

Comment: You are missing the point. There is no theorem which says a space is compact iff it is closed and bounded. It is true for subspaces of $\mathbb R^n.$ It is also true that if a metric space is compact, it is closed and bounded, but the reverse is not true, in general - a closed and bounded metric space is not necessarily compact.

Comment: An important part of the reason it is true for subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ is that $\mathbb R^n$ is a complete metric space. So any closed subspace is a complete metric space. But even completeness is not enough - there are complete metric spaces with closed and bounded subsets which are not compact.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's much confusion in your question. Lets try address all of it:

> Is the intersection of a closed interval with the rational closed in $\mathbb{Q}$

Yes. By the definition of subspace topology.

If you use metric (sequential) definition of being closed, then still yes. I encourage you to simply apply the definition and see it for yourself.

> If I say for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q} $ A set of the form $ [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} $ is compact as a subset of $\mathbb{Q} $ but not as a subset of $\mathbb{R} $?

Wrong. $[a,b]$ is compact, while $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not (even though it is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$). Being compact is much, much stronger than being closed, and in fact the property of being compact does not depend on the ambient space, i.e. $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact in any space, while $[a,b]$ is compact in all spaces.

I'm not exactly sure why you talk about compactness, when your original question is about being closed.

**EDIT:** So it seems you actually wanted to ask why $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact, even though it is closed and bounded. The property you refer to is known as [Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) or [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), depending on the definition of "compactness". Both theorems refer to closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not any metric space. In particular they do not apply to closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

> But a discrete set is compact if and only if it is finite.

Yes, but none of the spaces above is discrete.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I meant to ask is the set I defined compact in Q.

Comment: It is not compact (as I said: neither in $\mathbb{Q}$, nor in $\mathbb{R}$ nor in any other space). To see this you just have to pick a sequence of rationals convergent to an irrational. This sequence has no convergent subsequence in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: My original question is if it is closed and bounded why isn't it compact? Even though the underlying topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ is Hausdorff. Under what conditions is a closed and bounded set compact?

Comment: "Compact in $\mathbb Q$" is meaningless. A space is either compact or it isn't. The fact that it is contained in a bigger space has no bearing on compactness. @AbhishekBanerjee In general, closed and bounded does not imply compactness. But a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ which is closed and bounded is compact.

Comment: Thank you. Under what conditions does closed and bounded imply compactness?

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee Are you referring to [Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) or alternatively to [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)? Read both theorems closely: they refer to closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not to closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Why isn't the set $[a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ discrete? it's countablle right?

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee it is not discrete because for every rational $r\in (a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ there is a sequence of rationals $r-\frac{1}{n}$ convergent to $r$. In discrete space convergent sequences are eventually constant.

Comment: I had no idea discrete and countable were separate concepts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, these are two different things. Discrete means that points are isolated, while countable only refers to the underlying size of the set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139718/discussion-between-abhishek-banerjee-and-freakish).

Comment: In fact, a discrete space can be uncountable. (But a discrete subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is always countable.)

Comment: What would be an example of a discrete space that's uncountable?

Comment: @AbhishekBanerjee Given any set $X,$ we can define $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise. That metric gives the discrete topology on $X.$ A topology on $X$ is discrete if $\{x\}$ is an open set for all $x\in X.$ Equivalently, the discrete topology is the topology where every subset of $X$ is open.

Comment: Is this way of thinking correct? A compact subset of the reals can be covered with a finite number of open intervals no matter how small the intervals are. If this is correct, Intuitively why can't a finite number of very small open subsets of rationals cover the type of set in my question? Which points do they miss?

Is there an easy way to check whether a given set(under some general topology) is compact or not?

Comment: Please help. @ThomasAndrews